# Why can't you use a variable for an array size in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

According to my C++ textbook, the following expression:

```
cout << "Enter number of students\n";
cin >> number;
int score [number];
```

Is an **ILLEGAL** expression. 
I cannot use a variable for the array size.

Why can't I do this? (I'm not looking for an alternative, I haven't gotten into pointers, vectors etc, but I want to understand this behavior.)

Comment: Because C++ doesn't allow it.

Comment: Look at it from the POV of the compiler.  How much space should it reserve for your array when generating the object file?

Comment: In C `int score[number];` is legal.  Variable length arrays.

Comment: @MartinJames : Your reasoning is flawed, stack objects do not occupy space in the object file.  Also ISO C99 supports variable length arrays.

Comment: @Martin James In C as the post is tagged C.  `int score[number];` would need `number * sizeof(int)` bytes.  Thus is usually on the stack - quite easy for the compiler to generate code that allocates this space at run time.

Comment: Hmm.. you're right.  OP - I'm wrong:(

Comment: There is no technical reason it is not allowed. Some compilers support it as an extension.

Comment: @chux the post was mistagged; the question text makes it clear that it is asking about C++

Comment: OK, I was a wrong a bit:)

Comment: `std::vector<int> score(number); score[0] = 123;` this will work for you.

Comment: Short answer: It's not allowed because the C++ standard committee in the '90s decided not to allow it. However it has been proposed that C++17 will add support for this. As to why they didn't permit it originally: there wasn't really a good reason to force compiler vendors to support it, as C++ provides better ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It's a shame I can't select "best answer" for comments.

Comment: @Dimensions this will be closed as a duplicate anyway, the question linked by Neil Kirk has a lot more in-depth discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable length arrays were not supported in ISO C90/ANSI C89 from which C++ is derived.  While VLAs were added in C99 which deviates from C++, they are arguably unnecessary in C++ which has STL container classes to provide more flexible methods of storing multiple objects.

Comment: On the other hand, regarding "they are arguably unnecessary in C++", they are also arguably *useful* in C++ since we have an active proposal and -- almost nothing at all is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:  That the thing about "arguable" - you can argue about it.  I would not say "nothing at all is absolutely necessary", certain features in a programming language are necessary to make it "Turing Complete".  It is proposed, but no one on the ISO committee seems in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the compiler must know the amount of memory to allocate for an array at compile time. However, the value of a variable is not known until run time. This is why you are not allowed to use a variable for the size of an array.

If you are required to use arrays for a class project, I suggest using a `const` to define the maximum size that you will allow. Later on, you will learn how to user other techniques such as pointers and STL containers (such as std::vector).

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question. Also, no mention of vectors.

Comment: Note that this is an antique style, since 1998 it is preferred to write `std::vector<int> number;`

Comment: @NeilKirk Technically you're right that it doesn't answer the question, but it does provide an alternative for what the OP wants to achieve

Comment: Not what I was looking for. I'm not looking for an alternative, I haven't gotten into pointers, vectors etc. I want to understand.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That might be acceptable if the question were "how can I have a dynamically sized array in C++". But in this case, the OP is clearly aware of the restriction and likely how to get around it, it's a *why* question. For that reason I find it hard to believe that this answer does anything to lead the asker on the path towards the ultimate answer.

Comment: @Dimensions The code you are trying to use doesn't compile, so you must use **some** alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not explain why it is not allowed, other than the rules say not.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice :  You may have been better off adding a new answer and deleting this one rather than rendering all the comments moot.

Comment: @NeilKirk If there is more to it than what I have said here, feel free to provide your own answer.